# Unable to install SPA templates for .NET Core on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, single-page-application

As in topic I try to install some SPA templates following steps described here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

I have properly installed .NET Core 1.0.4 and NodeJS.

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

And then:

```
Restoring packages for /home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/scratch/restore.csproj...
  Installing System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1.
  Installing runtime.native.System.IO.Compression 4.1.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost 1.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.0.1.
  Installing System.Xml.XPath.XDocument 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Xml.XmlDocument 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.StackTrace 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 1.1.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.2.0.
  Installing System.Security.Principal 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Security.Claims 4.0.1.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Net.Security 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5.
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates 0.9.3.
  Installing Libuv 1.9.1.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic 1.3.0.
  Installing Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.0.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Net.Http 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy 1.0.5.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.2.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR 1.0.7.
  Installing System.Threading.Overlapped 4.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.VisualBasic 10.0.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Emit 4.0.1.
  Installing NETStandard.Library 1.6.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Buffers 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.2.0.
  Installing System.ComponentModel 4.0.1.
  Installing System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.1.0.
  Installing runtime.native.System 4.0.0.
  Installing Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.11.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.0.3.
  Installing System.Xml.XDocument 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Globalization.Extensions 4.0.1.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0.
  Installing System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles 4.0.0.
  Installing System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Linq.Expressions 4.1.1.
  Installing System.Linq.Parallel 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Net.Http 4.1.2.
  Installing System.Net.NameResolution 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Net.Requests 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Threading.Timer 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Net.Security 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Net.WebHeaderCollection 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Numerics.Vectors 4.1.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.DispatchProxy 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Metadata 1.3.0.
  Installing System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Resources.Reader 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Loader 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.2.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow 4.6.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.0.10.
  Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.3.0.
  Installing System.Collections 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Globalization 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Linq 4.1.0.
  Installing System.ObjectModel 4.0.12.
  Installing System.Reflection 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding.Extensions 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Reflection.Extensions 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Reflection.Primitives 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Text.Encoding 4.0.11.
  Installing System.Runtime 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Extensions 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Threading 4.0.11.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostResolver 1.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.0.7.
  Installing Microsoft.NETCore.Windows.ApiSets 1.0.1.
  Installing Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.0.1.
  Installing System.AppContext 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Numerics 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Collections.Concurrent 4.0.12.
  Installing System.Console 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0.
  Installing System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1.
  Installing System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Globalization.Calendars 4.0.1.
  Installing System.IO 4.1.0.
  Installing System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11.
  Installing System.IO.Compression 4.1.0.
  Installing System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.0.1.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1.
  Installing System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives 4.0.1.
  Generating MSBuild file /home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/scratch/obj/restore.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file /home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/scratch/obj/restore.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: /home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/scratch/obj/project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 2.04 sec for /home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/scratch/restore.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      /home/j/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

  Installed:
      112 package(s) to /home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/scratch/restore.csproj
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/runtime.native.system.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.filesystem.primitives.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.emit.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.xml.xdocument.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.console.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/runtime.native.system.security.cryptography.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.linq.expressions.4.1.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.net.primitives.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.net.webheadercollection.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualbasic.1.3.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.cryptography.csp.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/libuv.1.9.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.dynamic.runtime.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.diagnostics.tracing.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.typeextensions.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.text.encoding.codepages.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.principal.windows.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.globalization.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.tasks.parallel.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/runtime.native.system.io.compression.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.cryptography.openssl.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.runtime.coreclr.1.0.7.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.claims.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.text.encoding.extensions.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.resources.reader.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/runtime.native.system.net.http.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.linq.queryable.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.runtime.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.tasks.extensions.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.text.regularexpressions.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.collections.concurrent.4.0.12.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.memorymappedfiles.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.compression.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.net.sockets.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.compression.zipfile.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.globalization.calendars.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.globalization.extensions.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.appcontext.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.runtime.loader.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.thread.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.metadata.1.3.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.xml.xpath.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.runtime.extensions.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.net.http.4.1.2.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.diagnostics.process.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.collections.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.cryptography.encoding.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.platforms.1.0.2.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostpolicy.1.0.5.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.csharp.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver.1.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.objectmodel.4.0.12.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.extensions.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.linq.parallel.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.net.requests.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/netstandard.library.1.6.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.win32.primitives.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.net.security.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.filesystem.watcher.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers.1.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.overlapped.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.dotnethost.1.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.jit.1.0.7.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.dispatchproxy.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.1.0.5.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.componentmodel.annotations.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.1.3.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.cryptography.cng.4.2.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.windows.apisets.1.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.xml.xmldocument.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.principal.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.numerics.vectors.4.1.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.tasks.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.componentmodel.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.win32.registry.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.xml.readerwriter.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.io.filesystem.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.targets.1.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.netcore.targets.1.0.3.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.buffers.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.collections.immutable.1.2.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.cryptography.algorithms.4.2.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.threadpool.4.0.10.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.timer.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.diagnostics.tools.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/runtime.native.system.net.security.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.runtime.interopservices.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.xml.xpath.xdocument.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.emit.lightweight.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.diagnostics.debug.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.linq.4.1.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.resources.resourcemanager.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.4.6.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.runtime.numerics.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.spatemplates.0.9.3.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.visualbasic.10.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.net.nameresolution.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.text.encoding.4.0.11.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/microsoft.codeanalysis.common.1.3.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.security.cryptography.primitives.4.0.0.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.emit.ilgeneration.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.reflection.primitives.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Error: Package "/home/j/.templateengine/dotnetcli/v1.0.4/packages/system.runtime.handles.4.0.1.nupkg" is not a valid package specification
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.EnsureLoaded()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.GetTemplates(HashSet`1 templates)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Template.TemplateCreator.List(Boolean exactMatchesOnly, Func`3[] filters)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.PerformCoreTemplateQueryAsync()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.<EnterMaintenanceFlowAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.<ExecuteAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
```

And the question is... How to do it?!

Comment: What version of node did you install?

Comment: NodeJS version: 4.2.6
It's up to date on Ubuntu.
But the problem occurs with deserializing data by Newtonsoft lib.

Comment: I can't say for sure that is the problem, but the specs require node version 6, or higher; it says that in the prerequisites in the link you include. I installed all of this yesterday on my copy of Mint. I have node version 6.11 with npm 3.1. Same version of Core you have. It all worked.

Comment: NodeJS updated to 6.11. Npm is 3.10.10. Still no success...

Comment: If you run `dotnet new --help`, do you happen to see the templates (angular, aurelia, etc.) in the list?

Comment: nope. same error with deserialization as above

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks anyway. Got these templates on Windows machine.